# Convert protobuf-lite message to JSON and back

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

When using the regular Java Protobuf, you can use `JsonFormat` from `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util` to convert the Protobuf message to a JSON string, and back.

But does there exist a converter that works with Java Protobuf **Lite**? `JsonFormat` unfortunately supports the regular Java Protobuf messages only.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Protobuf Java developers [aren't aware](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/276#issuecomment-440724476) of any such converter so it is likely it doesn't exist.

Comment: @rupesh It's been a while so I don't remember the details, but I think this is the code:
https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-java/blob/8c1a278c32f67dab7d2188c7bc0e2e62eb9f4dae/core/src/main/java/clarifai2/grpc/JsonMarshaller.java